# Метод поиска не присваивает последний из соседних элементов нулю

Tags: java

Есть массив

```
  private int[][]inColor=new int[6][6];
```

Для удобства использую только внутренние ячейки (то есть внешние не заполняю данными).
пример

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 2 3 0
0 2 1 1 0
0 3 2 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Метод для поиска  принимает адрес выбранного элемента  и должен присваивать нулю соседние элементы с одинаковыми значениями,(типо как в bubble breaker).

Метод поиска

```
 private void serch(int x,int y){
int cik=inColor[x][y];
 if (x>0&x<6){
     if (y>0&y<6){
         if (inColor[x-1][y]==cik){
                 Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x - 1][y]);
                 Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x][y]);
                 inColor[x][y]=0;
                 serch(x - 1, y);


         }
         if (inColor[x+1][y]==cik){

                 Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x + 1][y]);
                 Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x][y]);
                 inColor[x][y]=0;
                 serch(x + 1, y);


         }
         if (inColor[x][y-1]==cik){

                 Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x ][y-1]);
                 Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x][y]);
                 inColor[x][y]=0;
                 serch(x , y-1);


         }
         if (inColor[x][y+1]==cik){

                 Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x ][y+1]);
                 Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x][y]);
                 inColor[x][y]=0;
                 serch(x , y+1);


         }

     }
 }
    print();

}
```

UPD проблема решена:

```
  private void serch(int x,int y,int cik){

 if (x>0&x<6){
     if (y>0&y<6){
         if (inColor[x-1][y]==cik){
                 Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x - 1][y]);
                 Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x][y]);
                 inColor[x][y]=0;
                 inColor[x-1][y]=0;
                 serch(x - 1, y,cik);


         }
         if (inColor[x+1][y]==cik){

                 Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x + 1][y]);
                 Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x][y]);
                 inColor[x][y]=0;
                 inColor[x+1][y]=0;
                 serch(x + 1, y,cik);


         }
         if (inColor[x][y-1]==cik){

                 Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x ][y-1]);
                 Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x][y]);
                 inColor[x][y]=0;
                 inColor[x][y-1]=0;
                 serch(x , y-1,cik);


         }
         if (inColor[x][y+1]==cik){

                 Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x ][y+1]);
                 Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x][y]);
                 inColor[x][y]=0;
                 inColor[x][y+1]=0;
                 serch(x , y+1,cik);


         }

     }
 }
    print();

}
```

Comment: Задание непонятно. Опишите его, что конкретно дано, и что нужно получить.

Comment: Вы одни и те же ячейки обходите снова и снова. Нужно проверять была ли уже обработана эта ячейка или нет.

Comment: исправил,аргументом сравнения сделал переменную,прошедшие присвоил 0,не помогло(

Comment: @Максим если проблема решена, то добавь ответ к своему же вопросу, получишь знак

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void serch(int x,int y,int cik){

   if (x>0&x<6){
 if (y>0&y<6){
     if (inColor[x-1][y]==cik){
             Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x - 1][y]);
             Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x][y]);
             inColor[x][y]=0;
             inColor[x-1][y]=0;
             serch(x - 1, y,cik);


     }
     if (inColor[x+1][y]==cik){

             Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x + 1][y]);
             Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x][y]);
             inColor[x][y]=0;
             inColor[x+1][y]=0;
             serch(x + 1, y,cik);


     }
     if (inColor[x][y-1]==cik){

             Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x ][y-1]);
             Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x][y]);
             inColor[x][y]=0;
             inColor[x][y-1]=0;
             serch(x , y-1,cik);


     }
     if (inColor[x][y+1]==cik){

             Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x ][y+1]);
             Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x][y]);
             inColor[x][y]=0;
             inColor[x][y+1]=0;
             serch(x , y+1,cik);


     }

 }
}
    print();

}
```